# CRM 2011 PRM Portal - error on solution import

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to import the PRM portal solution into a RTM CRM 2011 on-premise installation -currently busy taking snapshots of my envronment so I can install update rollup 1.

I get the following error when the upload is completed:

```
 ErrorCode: 0x80048425
 ErrorText: The Form XML does not conform to the required schema. 
 A schema validation error has been detected at line 0, position 0. 
 Details: The 'ordinalvalue' attribute is not declared.
```

The account entity is customized and I have a couple of other managed solutions imported,  an [OData Query Designer](http://crm2011odatatool.codeplex.com/) as well as the [Metadata Browser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/03/09/metadata-browser-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx).

Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed by installing [KB2461082](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/2461082/en) and updating CRM 2011 RC to CRM 2011 RTM